# How to do add signature to file using Apache camel

Tags: apache-camel, pgp, spring-camel

I need to add signature to a file not on the camel exchange, to a detached file using camel pgp. for example sample.json is plain file. after signing using camel PGP there should be two files, one is sample.json and sample.signed

Answer (score 1):

One approach is described [here](https://dzone.com/articles/pgp-encryption-and-decryption-with-apache-camel)

The filename / file extension could be edited before using the file producer like this:

```
.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant(filenameWithoutExtension + '.signed'))
```